# IP address "unknown"

Tags: proxy, ip-address

My forum logs are showing that I have a member who is using an IP address of "unknown". He is the only one that I am aware of who is able to do this.

We recently had to ban an abusive member from the forum and I know that he has used cloaking software and proxy servers before to make himself anonymous.
Should I be suspicious of this "unknown" IP address ?

Comment: Linux server? IIS?

Comment: I bit more information is needed if you want help. As it is it just comes down to 'should I be suspicious', which has no clear technical answer.

Comment: It might be useful to know which forum software you use, and you should compare with your web server access logs to get more detailed information about the user.  As @Hennes says, more information will get you a more complete explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's more likely that the address of the remote host is unusual or not supported by your host or host's network: I would guess the user is probably using IPv6 and that your host does not support it.